# Custom Constructor in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a custom class extending UIView. This class has some methods such as Drawerect...

Up to now, I was just putting it in my storyboard and telling that it belongs to the class. I would now allocate and place those objects dynamically. Is there a method so I could call :

```
[[MyObj alloc] initWithFrame:....]
```

Id be glad to find any help !

Comment: It's a subclass of UIView?  Then it inherits initWithFrame:.

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an uppercase letter, just saying ;-) 2) Have you actually _tried_ it? Because if you derived from `UIView`, you do have `initWithFrame:`. Or what's the problem?

Comment: @DarkDust of course, it starts with an uppercase ;) just renamed it to be clear in the example. Sorry if I have not been clear, in fact my mistake was to call MyCalss myObj=[[MyClass...... rather than MyClass *myObj... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own constructor in the header file of your class.
The return value is of type `id` , in its declaration in the main file you need to call a super initialization (for example `self = [super initWithFrame:CGRect]`) and then return the `self`. You can customize the parameters of your constructor in the header file to fit your needs.

Example for UIView:

**.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomView : UIView
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor;
```

**.m:**

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self) {

//after allocation you could set variables:

self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

}

return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: To be more consistent with Apple's `Coding Guidelines for Cocoa` consider renaming your initializer method 'initWithFrame:backgroundColor`.

Comment: I personally think it is more easy to understand it the way I wrote it down for beginners, so that they understand you can pass different parameters, and not just one. But feel free to down vote me and edit my answer. Although, yes you are right with the Coding Guidelines, I didn't want to offend you on this point.

Comment: If newcomers don't understand fundamentals of Objective-C, such as how to pass multiple parameters, it seems unlikely they'd be in a position understand the question, much less your answer. But it's a minor point, certainly not worth a down vote. I'll leave it up to you to decide whether to edit your answer.

Comment: There you go, I think it is easier to read with a meaningful title, but to suit the Guidelines... ;)

Comment: Please return `instancetype` rather than `id`: "Even though the compiler automatically converts methods that begin with “alloc,” “init,” or “new” and have a return type of id to return instancetype, it doesn’t convert other methods. Objective-C convention is to write instancetype explicitly for all methods." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html

Answer (score 3):

When instances of `UIView` are unarchived from an Interface Builder document, their `initWithFrame:` method isn't called. Instead, the unarchiver calls `initWithCoder:`. Ideally you should override both methods, and have them call a common method that provides a shared implementation of the initialization code. That way the views will be initialized correctly whether they're instantiated programmatically, or as a result of being unarchived. Here's an example:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) return nil;
    [self configureSubviews];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) return nil;
    [self configureSubviews];
    return self;
}

- (void)configureSubviews
{
    // Custom configuration code...
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the pattern you have to use when you want your custom view to work correctly when using *both* Interface Builder and manual initialization.